# Como cargar una tabla con datos de archivo ".json" a partir de una opción select JAVASCRIPT HTML

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, datatable

Tengo este codigo donde leo un archivo datos.json y cargo las opciones del select, ahora lo que quiero es que a partir de la opcion que seleccione, mostrar una tabla con datos de otro archivo datostabla.json

```
    <option value="AB">Alberta</option>
    <select id="locality-dropdown" name="locality"></select>

    <script>
        let dropdown = document.getElementById('locality-dropdown');
dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose State/Province';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const url = 'datos.json';

fetch(url)  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response  
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;

        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
          option.text = data[i].name;
          option.value = data[i].abbreviation;
          dropdown.add(option);
        }    
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
    </script>
```

Aqui les dejo parte del archivo datos.json

```
[   
{
      "name": "New Brunswick",
      "abbreviation": "NB"
   },
   {
      "name": "Newfoundland and Labrador",
      "abbreviation": "NL"
   },
   {
      "name": "Nova Scotia",
      "abbreviation": "NS"
   },
   {
      "name": "Yukon",
      "abbreviation": "YT"
   }
]
```

en esta parte les añado la parte del archivo datostabla.json para que lo revisen porfavor

```
[
   {
      "nombre": "Alberta",
      "abreviacion": "AB"
   },
   {
      "nombre": "Yukon",
      "abreviacion": "YT"
   }
]
```

Espero de su ayuda ya que no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en esto de javascript, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Pero cual es la duda, como estas intentando llenar la tabla?

Comment: Buen día Miguel, lo que quiero lograr es cargar las opciones de un archivo .json, y que al seleccionar una opción de esas, se llene una tablar en la pantalla con datos cargados de otro archivo .json. Espero darme a entender